# Prevent startup scripts from getting deleted on reboot in BusyBox

Tags: linux, init, busybox, buildroot, init.d

I'm running an open source "install environment", that acts as an enhanced boot loader utilizing facilities in a Linux/BusyBox environment called Open network install environment ( ONIE ). I want to run some scripts on every boot and I tried to do this by storing it in the init.d directory which is called from the inittab and consequently the rcS script. But whenever I store any script in the directory it gets deleted on reboot. Also I tried adding the commands in the scripts already present but they also get deleted leaving the original script as it. 
Also the OS is mostly ram based but I can store files in the /mnt mounted directory.

Comment: It seems like your system is not persistent ... For every boot the FS is restored from your ONIE maybe ... Is there any umount operation to do before rebooting the system ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)